# Driver for Epson Stylus Sx445w

Tags: drivers

Is there an Ubuntu 14.4 print driver for Epson Stylus Sx445w? If so, how do I get it?

Comment: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Comment: Thanks. Im new to this. Should I search for the printer name/model or? I tried different search criteria, but no luck :-(

Comment: Pasting `Sx445w` into the search form led me to the desired results. Unfortunately Epson doesn't let me link to the results directly.

Comment: There's a good chance that you won't need to install drivers for your printer/scanner combo. Plug it in and see what happens.

Comment: Searching for SX445W on the site linked only gives me results for SX440, and the drivers for this one don't work properly on the SX445W. If anyone who stumbles upon this question knows a different resource, I'd be glad to learn about it.